# category id in magento

Tags: php, magento, categories

I should start by saying i m new to this, but I got my website almost ready only this little detail is missing here and can't figure out how to put ii and hope you guys could help me with this. I installed the pagayo electronic theme on my website and so far is great but there is this at the bottom of the home page that should display my products and here is the code:

```
<reference name="content">
<block type="catalog/product_list" name="featured"template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
<action method="setCategoryId"><category_id>XXX</category_id></action>
<action method="setColumnCount"><count>5</count></action>
</block>
</reference>
```

so where the category_id>XXX what should i put there??? so far i have tried the name of category and product, the sku, the name of the subcategory my product is in and nothing seems to work, if you guys could help me with this and try it to explain it as clear as you could i would really appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here you have to put the id of the category id of the category you will get an id from catalog>manage category.

After going to manage category then click on the category which you want an id on right hand side you will get an id.

Hope it will help you.

[image]

Comment: thank you very much bro, i finally got it working, i never would of seing that id thing at the top of the website -.-. keep the good work :D